# How to remove <br> tag when RepeatLayout is Fow in DataList using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-controls

I want to skip "br" tag in case RepeatLayout property is set to "Flow" in `<asp:DataList>` control.

```
<asp:DataList
    id="dlstMovies"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    RepeatLayout="Flow"
    Runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%#Eval("Title")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Representation:

```
<span id="dlstMovies">
    <span>
         CHALTE CHALTE
    </span>
    <br />
    <span>
         ROCKY
    </span>
    <br />
    <span>
         SUNDAY
    </span>
</span>
```

I want to remove `<br />` tag after every `</span>`.
Can anybody suggest me way to achieve it?

Comment: I think you may need to overwrite the render function, or use something like a repeater if you want full control over markup.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Yes, I have tried by Repeater. It is working fine. I got solution of above issue. I needed to set RepeaterDirection properties to "Horizontal" and issue solved.